# Two Internet Connections - One LAN (Load Balancing?)

Tags: networking, router, internet, wan, load-balancer

If we have two different Internet Connections (one is substantially faster than the other), is there any way to connect both to the LAN, using some kind of load balancing to utilize both connections.

I understand that a single connection will only be able to use one internet connection at a time, however I am hoping that for example two clients connected to the same LAN would be able to use a separate internet connection each?

I have two routers available (a NETGEAR R7000 and a RT-N66U), however both only have one WAN port. Is it possible to have an internet connection attached to each but have both on the same LAN?

I do also have an old PC I could install pfSense on as a number of people have suggested this as a solution. I am concerned however that the box would become a bottleneck and limit the overall speed of the internet, since one of the Net connections is super-fast fibre.

Comment: carrying traffic at Internet speeds ( > 1Gbps) will not tax the system much at all. I'd try the pfSense route, and upgrade components in the old PC if you find that they are suboptimal. Otherwise, without a dual-wan router, it will be very difficult to do what you are imagining without spending money somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Frank has mentioned above, you may need a dual-wan router.

Load balancer is more common in corpnet. We will use two enterprise routers to build a router cluster. If we have 200 clients, 100 will get the internet through one link and the others will through another link.

Also, it will provide the gateway HA. Even one of the router goes down, all users are still able to connect to the internet.

If you are interesting in it, you may try to search HSRP, VRRP, GLBP.

Answer (score 0):

A simple set up is to connect both the routers' WAN ports to their respective modems, and then connect the two routers' LAN ports to a switch, making sure that each of the two routers occupies a different subnet, but both have the same broad subnet mask (255.255.254.0 or 255.255.224.0). A device will only recognize one of the two routers' DHCP responses, so it is best to turn off both routers' DHCP servers and use one device that recognizes both routers as two separate default gateways to the Internet (and obviously, the first default gateway should be the one with the faster connection).